# How to achieve a retroreflector material in Eevee

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes, reflection

A simple way to obtain a very good retroreflective material in Cycles is by connecting the Incoming output of the Geometry Node to the Normal input of Principled BSDF (ang raising the Metallic property).
In Eevee, with the same configuration, a dotted and striped shading is obtained. How to fix this, obtaining a smooth appearance?
[image: Eevee result of connecting Geometry Incoming to BSDF Normal]

Answer (score 6):

Just found a possible solution: the dotted and striped appearance can be eliminated by using a snap factor on the Incoming vector:
[image: Retroreflective material in Eevee with vector snap]